# Can we create JSON using JsonBuilder for the following JSON?

Tags: json, groovy

I want to create the below JSON using JsonBuilder.

```
"isOut": false,
"baleRun": {
    "incData": true,
    "appendCricket": [{
        "min": 10,
        "max": 32,
        "price": "10"
    }]
}
```

I have tried below code to create it:-

```
import groovy.json.*

def builder = new JsonBuilder()
def root = builder.baleRun{                
    incData true
    builder.appendCricket [
    {
        min 10
        max 32      
        price "10000"
     }
    ]                     
 }
```

Getting below error:-

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: appendCricket for 
class: groovy.json.JsonBuilder error.
```

Any idea how to produce this?

Comment: remove `appendCricket` from `builder.appendCricket`

Comment: but this is required as per the required JSON, I have mentioned

Comment: then do `baleRun{ appendCricket{...} }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to build a Map for the data you want, then pass this to the builder in the constructor:

```
import groovy.json.*

def data = [
    isOut: false,
    baleRun: [
        incData: true,
        appendCricket: [
            [min: 10, max: 32, price: '10']
        ]
    ]
]
def json = new JsonBuilder(data).toString()
```

Comment: how to append the same json value to other JSON? Is there any specific code required?

Comment: Not sure what you mean...  Json is a string...  Add them together?

Comment: Okey, I'll post another question for this.. And will explain it there,,,

Comment: I have posted questions with explanation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275186/how-to-append-json-built-using-jsonbuilder-to-other-json-using-groovy

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to create it using map, like @tim_yates suggested.

Of course, it is also possible to create the way you started with. Should be taken care for array, see in line:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
json {
    isOut false
    baleRun {
      incData true
      appendCricket( [
      {
          min 10
          max 32      
          price "10000"
       }
      ])
    }
 }

println json.toPrettyString()
```

Quickly try the same online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/3vrZL0)</kbd>

Comment: Can we append the same json to the main JSON at particular place?

Comment: I don't want the outer curly bracket.. Like I have mentioned above. This gives me output with outside curly bracket