# How to append JSON built using JsonBuilder to other JSON using groovy?

Tags: json, groovy

With reference to this question's solution :- [Building JSON using JsonBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260525/can-we-create-json-using-jsonbuilder-for-the-following-json)

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
json {
    isOut false
    baleRun {
      incData true
      appendCricket( [
      {
         min 10
         max 32      
        price "10000"
      }
     ])
   }
}

println json.toPrettyString()
```

Output:-

```
{
"isOut": false,
"baleRun": {
    "incData": true,
    "appendCricket": [
        {
            "min": 10,
            "max": 32,
            "price": "10000"
        }
       ]
    }
}
```

Where outside curly bracket is not required (In my case)

I have another JSON where I need to insert newly created JSON:-

```
def newJSON = '''{
    "count": 6,
    "max": "1",
    "bale": false,
    "cricketDetails": {
        "cricketCategory": [
            {
                "ball": 16,
                "swing": true,
                "code": "2",
                "umpireStatus": [
                    {
                        "code": "TYUR",
                        "avail": 0,
                        "position": 1,
                        "request": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "TGRE",
                        "avail": 0,
                        "position": 2,
                        "request": ""
                    }
                ],
                "min": "0",
                "extraCover": 12,
                "price": "DNR",
                "program": "1 Day"
            }
        ]
    },
    "fourRuns": 4,
    "sixRuns": 6
}'''
```

I have tried below code to add JSON1 (which is created using JsonBuilder) to JSON2 (Where I need to insert) at particular position:-

```
 newJson.cricketDetails.cricketCategory.getAt(0).json = json
```

Actual Output I needed:-

```
{
"count": 6,
"max": "1",
"bale": false,
"cricketDetails": {
    "cricketCategory": [{
        "ball": 16,
        "swing": true,
        "code": "2",
        "umpireStatus": [{
            "code": "TYUR",
            "avail": 0,
            "position": 1,
            "request": ""
        },
        {
            "code": "TGRE",
            "avail": 0,
            "position": 2,
            "request": ""
        }],
        "isOut": false,
        "baleRun": {
            "incData": true,
            "appendCricket": [{
                "min": 10,
                "max": 32,
                "price": "10000"
            }]
        },
        "min": "0",
        "extraCover": 12,
        "price": "DNR",
        "program": "1 Day"
    }]
},
"fourRuns": 4,
"sixRuns": 6
}
```

How can I achieve this? Also, If I try above mentioned code, outer curly bracket is being added every time with "json" as KEY. You can see from my output, I do not need and key here.

Comment: Another code, I have tried is - newJson.cricketDetails.cricketCategory.getAt(0).content = json.content, But still in output I can see "content" key is added. I don't want this and the out curly bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**newJSON** is string. **json** is instance of JsonBuilder that have method getContent which will return json as map.

So first of all you need to parse newJSON to map.

Then you can easily insert one map to other.

And finally produce json from this map as string.

```
def parsedJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(newJSON) // parse to map

parsedJson.cricketDetails.cricketCategory.getAt(0) << json.content // modify map

def out = new JsonOutput()
println out.prettyPrint(out.toJson(parsedJson)) //output final json
```